# mpiexec checkpointing error (RPi)

Tags: runtime-error, raspberry-pi, mpi, blcr

When I try to run an application (just a simple hello_world.c doesn't work) I receive this error every time:

```
mpiexec -ckpointlib blcr -ckpoint-prefix /tmp/ -ckpoint-interval 10 -machinefile /tmp/machinefile -n 1 ./app_name

[proxy:0:0@masterpi] requesting checkpoint
[proxy:0:0@masterpi] checkpoint completed
[proxy:0:0@masterpi] requesting checkpoint
[proxy:0:0@masterpi] HYDT_ckpoint_checkpoint (./tools/ckpoint/ckpoint.c:111): Previous checkpoint has not completed.[proxy:0:0@masterpi] HYD_pmcd_pmip_control_cmd_cb (./pm/pmiserv/pmip_cb.c:905): checkpoint suspend failed
[proxy:0:0@masterpi] HYDT_dmxu_poll_wait_for_event (./tools/demux/demux_poll.c:77): callback returned error status
[proxy:0:0@masterpi] main (./pm/pmiserv/pmip.c:206): demux engine error waiting for event
[mpiexec@masterpi] control_cb (./pm/pmiserv/pmiserv_cb.c:202): assert (!closed) failed
[mpiexec@masterpi] HYDT_dmxu_poll_wait_for_event (./tools/demux/demux_poll.c:77): callback returned error status
[mpiexec@masterpi] HYD_pmci_wait_for_completion (./pm/pmiserv/pmiserv_pmci.c:197): error waiting for event
[mpiexec@masterpi] main (./ui/mpich/mpiexec.c:331): process manager error waiting for completion
```

I want just to make a checkpoint and nothing else (and restart later).

Thanks in advance

### UPDATE:

I have tried with MPICH2, no chance. Or maybe I'm wrong somewhere...

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ mpiexec -n 1 -ckpointlib blcr -ckpoint-prefix /tmp/  -ckpoint-interval 2 ./test3
Count to: 0
[proxy:0:0@raspberrypi] requesting checkpoint
[proxy:0:0@raspberrypi] checkpoint completed
Count to: 1
[proxy:0:0@raspberrypi] requesting checkpoint
[proxy:0:0@raspberrypi] HYDT_ckpoint_checkpoint (/tmp/mpich/mpich2-1.5/src/pm/hydra/tools/ckpoint/ckpoint.c:111): Previous checkpoint has not completed.[proxy:0:0@raspberrypi] HYD_pmcd_pmip_control_cmd_cb (/tmp/mpich/mpich2-1.5/src/pm/hydra/pm/pmiserv/pmip_cb.c:902): checkpoint suspend failed
[proxy:0:0@raspberrypi] HYDT_dmxu_poll_wait_for_event (/tmp/mpich/mpich2-1.5/src/pm/hydra/tools/demux/demux_poll.c:77): callback returned error status
[proxy:0:0@raspberrypi] main (/tmp/mpich/mpich2-1.5/src/pm/hydra/pm/pmiserv/pmip.c:210): demux engine error waiting for event
[mpiexec@raspberrypi] control_cb (/tmp/mpich/mpich2-1.5/src/pm/hydra/pm/pmiserv/pmiserv_cb.c:201): assert (!closed) failed
[mpiexec@raspberrypi] HYDT_dmxu_poll_wait_for_event (/tmp/mpich/mpich2-1.5/src/pm/hydra/tools/demux/demux_poll.c:77): callback returned error status
[mpiexec@raspberrypi] HYD_pmci_wait_for_completion (/tmp/mpich/mpich2-1.5/src/pm/hydra/pm/pmiserv/pmiserv_pmci.c:196): error waiting for event
[mpiexec@raspberrypi] main (/tmp/mpich/mpich2-1.5/src/pm/hydra/ui/mpich/mpiexec.c:325): process manager error waiting for completion
```

Test3-Code:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mpi.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    int rank;
    int size;
    int i = 0;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

    MPI_Status status;

    if (rank == 0) {
        for(i; i <=100; i++){
            int j = 0;
            while(j < 100000000){
                j++;
            }
            printf("Count to: %i\n", i);
        }
    } else {
    }

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;

}
```

I just need to have one successful checkpoint and to show the restart.
If someone has a working example (irrelevant what it makes, simple working "Hello World" would make me happy!) I would be very glad.

Happy new year!

Comment: Which version of MPICH are you using?

Comment: mpich-3.0.4 (stable release)

Comment: also my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20532769/restart-a-mpi-slave-after-checkpoint-before-failure-on-armv6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the problem was with the too small interval for checkpointing.
Setting it to 20s or more has solved this (but not the other :( ) problem.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the checkpoint/restart code in MPICH 3.0.4 is known to be buggy at the moment. That will hopefully get fixed in a future release. It looks like you're probably using it correctly. It's possible that if you go back to a previous version, you might have better luck.