# OpenMPI on Raspberry Pi with Checkpoint/Restart support

Tags: arm, mpi, raspberry-pi, openmpi, blcr

I have a simple question.
Does **OpenMPI** on Raspberry PI i.e. ARM provide the Checkpoint/Restart feature?
I have MPICH with BLCR but I can't restart any application.
(MPICH and BLCR are built myself)
So I would try out with OpenMPI. *(yes I mean OpenMPI because I do not get any answer to my MPICH Problem)*
I saw that there are openmpi-bin, openmpi-common, openmpi-doc packages but no openmpi-checkpoint available.

Thank you in advance and a happy new year!

Comment: MPICH and Open MPI are two different iplementations of MPI - which one are you using? Does it come from a prebuilt package or did you build it yourself?

Comment: tried with MPICH 1.5 and MPICH 3.0.4.
MPI works on the rpis. blcr works, too. but with blcr i have problems to restart a mpi application.
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20794796/rpi-blcr-mpich-checkpoint-restart-issue)

Answer (score 1):

Ah. In that case, the best answer I have is "supposedly, for some versions".
From the OpenMPI FAQ (http://www.open-mpi.org/faq/?category=ft):

*The checkpoint/restart support was last released as part of the v1.6 series. The v1.7 series and the Open MPI trunk do not support this functionality (most of the code is present in the repository, but it is known to be non-functional in most cases). This feature is looking for a maintainer. Interested parties should inquire on the developers mailing list.*

BLCR itself has "experimental" ARM support. I know that someone tested this during development, but that may well have been 3 years ago.

Comment: BLCR works well with non mpi applications. I have a problem with restarting a mpi application. I get a checkpoint file but when I try to restart the processes are in a zombie-state.